# Use string function with raw string

Tags: python

I am writing a program that will encrypt words from a list until the hash matches the one you are trying to decrypt.

The problem I am having is that when the hash is encrypted,
it does not loose any of the whitespace characters and I get hashes like:

`b'\x0by\x07\xb4\xe8\xd9\x90d\xaa\xd9\xe6\x1d\xfa\x92\xc2\xaf`

and **not** `63eb1dea1692fc53800b20be983e9a8b`

Is there any way I can get rid of all whitespaces before I encrypt?

This is my code:

```
import hashlib
def computeMD5hash(string):
    m = hashlib.md5()
    m.update(string.encode('utf-8'))
    md5string=m.digest()
    return md5string

wordlist = open('wordlist.txt', 'r')
words = wordlist.readlines()
words = [x.strip('\n') for x in words]
print("Searching...")
for i in words:
    for x in words:
        print(i+x)
        out = computeMD5hash(i+x)
        print(out)
        if out == '63eb1dea1692fc53800b20be983e9a8b':
            print(i+x)
            break
```

Edit:
Sorry, it's not just whitespace, but there aren't supposed to be backslashes in the hash, and I feel like either the encoding is wrong or my method for encrypting is not correct. All I know is that the output is wrong, and I have checked it against multiple sources.

Comment: Where is the whitespace?

Comment: Sorry, it's not just whitespace, but there aren't supposed to be backslashes in the hash, and I feel like either the encoding is wrong or my method for encrypting is not correct. All I know is that the output is wrong, and I have checked it against multiple sources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def computeMD5hash(string):
    m = hashlib.md5()
    m.update(string.encode('utf-8'))
    md5string=m.hexdigest() # use hexdigest instead
    return md5string
```